# Subscription Error on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subscription

I setup SSRS Express 2012 reporting on my computer and I created report. Now I want to send mail this report with schedule.
That's why I went to URL link and I opened my Data source and subscription page.
But when I open subscription page, I face to this error.

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to move to the developer edition of SQL Server, and SSRS. Of course, I am assuming you are only using this local install for development work.

Otherwise, change the SQL Server/SSRS edition to one where this functionality is supported; Standard edition or higher.

Comment: Thanks for you help.